# Perguntas que se extendem para o infinito e além

Tags: debate

Um exemplo clássico:
[Enviando variável do PHP externo para o Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68640/enviando-vari%C3%A1vel-do-php-externo-para-o-javascript)

Me dá calafrio na espinha quando vejo esses tópicos.

O autor posta um espaguete de códigos misturando sintaxes JS, PHP e HTML e tudo que sabe dizer é, "não funciona".

Então vem uma avalanche de respostas das quais o AP, que já está confuso, fica mais confuso ainda.

Obviamente que não vai ter uma resposta exata pois para resolver o problema é preciso fazer o AP entender os fundamentos básicos de linguagens de programação e entender o que realmente ele quer. 
Em outras palavras, "o buraco está mais embaixo".

A minha dúvida é, devo votar para fechar o tópico como "amplo demais" ou algo similar ?

Ou talvez pedir para que continuem no chat.

O meu ponto de vista é de que esse tipo de conteúdo não agrega valor algum a comunidade.
Pelo menos não do modo como está.

Comment: Não seria exagerado fechar como "Erro de digitação". Clássico caso que você resolve um problema e vão aparecendo cada vez mais...

Comment: Então Daniel, eu acho que está pergunta é uma duplicata (existe algumas perguntas com o mesmo proposito, códigos diferentes), na resposta não precisa ser em cima do código do autor, o que ele precisa é entender *como* compartilhar as "variáveis" e apenas isto (minha opinião).

Comment: Guilherme, esse é um dos problemas pois para explicar ao AP sobre como resolver, temos que praticamente dar uma aula expresso.  Então, uma das finalidades do StackOverflow é também dar aulas "particulares"?      Eu critiquei isso em outras oportunidades pois não concordo em fazer o serviço de terceiros, não gostaria que isso aqui virasse um centro de suporte técnico gratuito. Tudo bem quem quer fazer serviço de graça.. Mas deveriam ter ciência de que desvalorizam a profissão e a si mesmos. Uma ajuda, uma dica, ok, tudo bem, mas ficar ali atendendo o AP como se fosse um cliente.. não concordo.

Comment: As minhas ajudas são sempre direcionadas com o seguinte ideal em mente: vai ser útil pra outras pessoas além do AP. Ai, se eu julgo que tem esse potencial, eu me esforço mesmo que o AP não seja tão merecedor (por inocência ou mesmo má vontade). As vezes isso gera muitos comentários (e até perguntas aqui no meta, que me fizeram quase que me arrepender de ter insistido). Mas, acho que faz parte. Antes de (ou junto com) votar pra fechar, creio que vale tentar instruir para que o foco da pergunta seja tornado mais específico, ou até para que ela seja dividida em duas ou mais perguntas. :)

Comment: E, só pra constar, entendo e compartilho dos seus calafrios. Pra mim, eles já ocorrem quando eu bato o olho e a pergunta tem um monte de tags de 4 ou 5 tecnologias/assuntos diferentes.

Comment: Com o tempo a gente aprender a fechar a página da pergunta assim que tem os calafrios. Banir totalmente esse tipo de pergunta *help desk* é algo que a SE não quer fazer (pelo menos é assim que enxergo a postura deles, não só aqui mas na rede toda).

Comment: Eu não gosto desse tipo de pergunta, geralmente eu passo o olho, vejo se não existe algo de muito errado com ela e se não houver eu simplesmente fecho a janela. Entretanto, eu não gostar de responder esse tipo de pergunta não necessariamente implica que ninguém mais goste. Bem ou mal existem 3 respostas para essa pergunta, não sei se a motivação de quem respondeu é apenas caçar reputação ou se para eles de repente foi agradável respondê-la. Por mim perguntas similares a essa podem permanecer abertas por esse motivo. A não ser é claro que você não tenha escolhido o melhor dos exemplos.

Comment: Eu procuro respeitar a postura da rede Stack Overflow. Mas fica essa contradição do "conteúdo de qualidade" e ao mesmo tempo permitir esse "lixo".. Claro, sem querer ofender os novatos que postam  "lixo" pois a grande maioria faz por falta de conhecimento, então devemos ter compreensão.  No entanto, nesse caso específico, Luiz Vieira, particularmente não vejo valor algum para a comunidade. Por isso acho em vão ficar tentado ajudar a resolver esse tipo de questão.. é perda de tempo e acúmulo de lixo cibernético. Poderia ter uma flag para marcar uma questão como "sem valor comunitário".. enfim

Comment: Eu gosto desse tipo de pergunta. Tento levar o AP a bom porto, guiando-o através de comentários. Não gosto de responder porque ai estaria a dar-lhe a *papinha* toda em vez de o ajudar a tentar perceber a lógica dos seus problemas. No fim com o AP a entender o que se passa, e **se achar que não vai ajudar mais ninguém no futuro**, fecho como "Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro..."

Comment: @DanielOmine eu também não concordo com aulas particulares e por este motivo mesmo que eu disse, **na resposta não precisa ser em cima do código do autor, o que ele precisa é entender como compartilhar as "variáveis" e apenas isto**, ou seja não é para arrumar o código dele e fazer o trabalho dele, é apenas para dar uma resposta que sirva para todos usuários com duvidas semelhantes e que não seja a solução completa resolvida e o autor da pergunta tentar corrigir o código seguindo a sua resposta.

Comment: Posso estar errado mas acredito que a  probabilidade de alguma informação nesse topico específico ser útil para terceiros - não diretamente envolvidos no tópico - seja "zero".

Comment: Não é a informação atual mas sim a informação que uma nova resposta poderá conseguir passar, uma resposta que realmente explique sobre o compartilhamento de "variáveis" e por isto eu acho que a pergunta é uma **duplicata**, porque já existem respostas no SOpt que explicam como compartilhar variáveis PHP com outras páginas e com o JavaScript.

Comment: rsrsr então ... mais uma razão para afirmar que é um topico inutil.

Comment: apenas um adendo, não critico quem responde a tais tópicos, é apenas ponto de vista sobre o que penso de tais tópicos.